# How can I add a transition for this growing div?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, transition

I am trying to add transition to a growing div.
Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fL5rLr2y/
This jsfiddle represent my real world problem.
I have the following markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%; } .container {
    position: relative;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: blue; }

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red; }

.inner.open {
    height: initial;
    bottom: 20px; }
```

Here is my js:

```
$('.inner').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

I am trying to add the transition using pure css. How can I do it?
If pure css solution is not possible, how can I use js in order to solve it?

**UPDATE**
After a lot of investigations, it seems that using calc is the only option to do it in pure css.
Unfortunately I have bed experience with calc, especially with safari and mobile (browser crashes and other surprises). I prefer to avoid using calc for now and use javascript solution to simulate that.
Any idea how?

Comment: what type of transition are you trying to add?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you're looking for it to NOT snap open? Probably won't work for `height: initial;` but should work for a set height: `transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;`.

Comment: @henser: Transition for the bottom or for the height. Press on the red area and it will expended.

Comment: check my answer ... is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Have you tried to use CSS3 transitions?

Comment: @JayantVarshney: You are welcome to help me using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dynamic height by updating the style below. Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/fL5rLr2y/8/

```
.inner {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: red;
         -webkit-transition: height 1s;
        transition:height 1s;
    }

    .inner.open {
        height: calc(100% - 50px); /* top 30px + bottom 20px */

    }
```

Or you can use jQuery animation. See the output at http://jsfiddle.net/8mn90ueb/3/ and code below

Remove the **open** class and the **toggle** type

```
    $('.inner').click(function() {
    var currentHeight = $(this).height();
    if(currentHeight > 50){
        currentHeight = 50;
    }
    else{
      currentHeight = $('.container').height() - 50;
    }
     $(this).animate({
         height:currentHeight
     },1000,function(){});

});
```

Comment: I have bad experience with calc especially with safari and mobile (browser crashes and other surprises). I prefer to avoid using calc for now and use javascript to simulate that. Any idea how?

Comment: @Naor Try http://jsfiddle.net/8mn90ueb/1/ . You can update the calculations according to yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `.inner` and `.inner.open` classes as demonstrated below ... you need to set a predetermined height to `.open`

If you're going to use CSS3 transitions you can opt to use calc() to determine your `.open` height without compromising browser compatibility.

Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fL5rLr2y/10/)

```
.inner {
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 50px;
background-color: red;

transition: height 1s;
-webkit-transition: height 1s;
-moz-transition: height 1s;
-ms-transition: height 1s;
    -o-transition: height 1s;
}

.inner.open {
    height: calc(100%-50px);
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for the opposite way. Moreover, the transition starts from 75% bottom and not from 50px height.

Comment: This is not good either because the open state is 200px height and is not stretched to 20px bottom.

Comment: I can't give it a height because the container's height is percentage. I don't know how much is 20px comparing to 100%. This is incorrect.

Comment: well ... did you try using calc(100%-50px) as suggested here?

Comment: I thought about calc many before writing here. I have a very bed experience with calc. I prefer javascript solution over calc. Do you have any idea how to solve this using js?

Comment: Do you mind sharing your bad experiences with calc()? Yes, I have an idea on how to do it easily with jQuery's animate() or slide() methods or more painfully with javascript using setInterval ...

Comment: Safari and mobile browsers don't really like calc(). They tend to crash, especially if there is a non-static element in the story. Don't want to do it with jQuery animate() or slide(), but by assigning css properties to support the transition.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property is what you need. The height calculation of `.inner` is now made with jQuery.

#### Demo with jQuery calculation

```js
$('.inner').click(function() {
  var parentHeight = $(this).parent().outerHeight() - 50; // Get parent height - 50px
  var innerHeight = $(this).outerHeight(); // Get inner height
  
  
  // if the inner height = 50px then change height to the parent height calculation
  // otherwise return to 50 height
  if (innerHeight === 50) {
    $(this).height(parentHeight);
  } else {
    $(this).height(50);
  }

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

#### If you change your mind about calc()

The CSS [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property is what you need along with `height: calc(100% - 50px)` on the open class. The calc gets you a 30px gap at the top and 20px gap at the bottom when open. The `bottom` property has been removed.

**Compatibility:**

- The [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property is unlikely to need browser prefixes. [Have a look here](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition) for its browser support.
- [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) enjoys widespread support including, importantly, IE9 + support. [More information here](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc). To provide a fallback height for IE 8 and below, provide a normal height percentage property *before* the calc height for older browsers to use. Something like `height: 70%`

#### Demo with CSS only

```js
$('.inner').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}
.inner.open {
  height: 70%; /* pick a percentage height for IE 8 and below */
  height: calc(100% - 50px); /* 100% height minus 30px at the top + 20px at the bottom */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have bad experience with calc especially with safari and mobile (browser crashes and other surprises). I prefer to avoid using calc for now and use javascript to simulate that. Any idea how?

Comment: Is jQuery ok? Example added. I am no javascript guru, I just know the basics. If jQuery is not ok I can replicate in Javascript :)